# Why do I get a "no matching constructor error?

Tags: c++, constructor

I want my code to take a `name`, `mail` and `car` as argument types, and I try to do so in a class named `Person`. In `main()`, I try to give that class a variable `a` which I can call later in `cout`. However, I get this exact error:

> no matching constructor for initialization of "Person"

How can I fix this?

The h. file

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "car.h"
#include <string>

class Person{
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string mail;
        Car* car;

    public: 
        Person(std::string name, std::string mail);
        Person(std::string name, std::string, Car* car);
        void setMail(std::string mail);
        std::string getMail() const;
        std::string getName() const;
        bool hasAvailableFreeSeats();
        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Person& person);
};
```

The cpp file:

```
#include "person.h"


std::string Person:: getMail() const{
    return mail;
}

std:: string Person:: getName() const{
    return name;
}

void Person:: setMail(std::string mail){
    this -> mail = mail;
}

Person:: Person(std::string name, std::string mail) : Person(name, mail, nullptr){};

Person::Person(std::string name, std::string, Car* car) : name{name}, mail{mail}, car{car}{};

bool Person:: hasAvailableFreeSeats(){
    if (car != nullptr){
        return car-> hasFreeSeats();
    }
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Person& person){
    return os << person.name << ": " << person.mail << "\n";
}
```

main:

```
#include "person.h"

int main(){
    std::string name{"Ola Normann"};
    std::string mail{"ola.normann@norge.no"};
    std::unique_ptr<Car> car{new Car{5}};
    Person a{name, mail, std::move(car)};
};
```

Comment: A `std::unique_ptr<Car>` cannot be implicitly converted to a `Car*` - perhaps you meant to call `.get` ( or `.release`) instead of using `std::move`?

Comment: @UnholySheep so you want me to swap std::move to .release? Don't know exactly what that part does anyway, got it from. my teacher.

Comment: @Kaku Your teacher wrote all the contents in `main`?

Comment: @user17732522 that's because it's a pointer to a different class from another file. The std:: unique_ptr in main is the test code i got from my teacher to test if the code was correct

Comment: @Kaku Then your teacher wants you to store a `std::unique_ptr<Car>`, not a `Car*`, inside your class. (For whatever reason I cannot really discern. `Car` directly would probably also work fine.)

Comment: Propably you was supposed to use an std:::unique_ptr in your constructor insteas of a plain pointer.

Comment: @user17732522 and gerum thanks. I'll try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you have a typo in your 3-parameter `Person` constructor.  The 2nd parameter has no name assigned to it, so you end up initializing the `mail` class member with itself, not with the caller's input:

```
Person::Person(std::string name, std::string, Car* car) : name{name}, mail{mail}, car{car}{};
                                            ^ no name here!                ^ member!
```

That should be this instead:

```
Person::Person(std::string name, std::string mail, Car* car) : name{name}, mail{mail}, car{car}{};
                                             ^ has a name now!                  ^ parameter!
```

---

Now, that being said, your `main()` code is passing 3 values to the `Person` constructor:

```
Person a{name, mail, std::move(car)};
```

Your `Person` class only has 1 constructor that accepts 3 parameters:

```
Person(std::string name, std::string, Car* car);
```

In `main()`, your `name` and `mail` variables are `std::string` objects, which is fine, but your `car` variable is a `std::unique_ptr<Car>` object, not a `Car*` pointer. `std::move(car)` will return a `std::unique_ptr<Car>&&` rvalue reference, which `Person` does not accept, hence the compiler error.  `std::unique_ptr` is not implicitly convertible to a raw pointer.  You would have to use its `get()` method instead:

```
Person a{name, mail, car.get()};
```

Which defeats the purpose of using `std::unique_ptr` in the first place.  You should instead change the `Person` class to hold a `std::unique_ptr` object instead of a raw pointer, eg:

.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include "car.h"

class Person{
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::string mail;
        std::unique_ptr<Car> car;

    public: 
        ...
        Person(std::string name, std::string mail);
        Person(std::string name, std::string mail, std::unique_ptr<Car> car);
        ...
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "person.h"

...

Person::Person(std::string name, std::string mail) : Person(name, mail, nullptr){};

Person::Person(std::string name, std::string, std::unique_ptr<Car> car) : name{name}, mail{mail}, car{std::move(car)}{};

...
```

main

```
#include "person.h"

int main(){
    std::string name{"Ola Normann"};
    std::string mail{"ola.normann@norge.no"};
    std::unique_ptr<Car> car{new Car{5}};
    Person a{name, mail, std::move(car)};
    // alternatively:
    // Person a{name, mail, std::make_unique<Car>(5)};
};
```

Comment: that very much solved the problem. Awesome, thanks!!

Comment: A little follow up, when you in main set std::unique_ptr<Car> car{new Car{5}}; that will set the value of Car to 5 in whatever place the thing points on?

Comment: @Kaku `new Car{5}` constructs a new `Car` object passing `5` to its constructor, and then returns a `Car*` pointer to that object. `std::unique_ptr<Car> car{...}` then takes ownership of that pointer. Note that, in the (unlikely) event that `unique_ptr`'s constructor fails, the `Car` object will be leaked. Using `auto car = std::make_unique<Car>(5)` instead is safer.